# Boundary of hyperbolic spaces and isometries

Tags: reference-request, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Do you know a good reference about boundary of hyperbolic spaces (following Gromov) and the classification of the isometries acting on hyperbolic space (hyperbolic, parabolic and elliptic isometries)? I am specially interested by the hyperbolic isometries, with the notions of axis and translation length.

Comment: I don't have a reference at hand, but the boundary of hyperbolic plane is isomorphic to the real projective line. If you know the effect of an isometry on the boundary, you know the transformation. If there are two fixed points on the boundary, you either have a reflection (which you can recognize as an involution) or, depending on order, a translation or a glide reflection. If you have a single fixed point, you have an ideal rotation. If you have no fixed points on the boundary, the fixed points in $\mathbb C\mathrm P^1$ represent a single hyperbolic point, the center of a rotation. Useful?

Comment: Did you try [Ghys-de la Harpe](http://books.google.com/books?id=FIGBAAAAIAAJ) or [Bridson-Haefliger](http://books.google.com/books?id=3DjaqB08AwAC) or [Coornaert-Delzant-Papadopoulos](http://books.google.com/books?id=F78ZAQAAIAAJ)? @MvG: The question seems to be about [$\delta$-hyperbolic spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Δ-hyperbolic_space)

Comment: @Martin: The book of Coornaert, Delzant and Papadopoulos seems to be exactly what I seek, however it is not available in my university... Do you know an equivalent reference?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't. When I learned about Gromov-hyperbolicity in the Old Millennium, the references I gave were pretty much the only introductory books available. I don't know the newer books on the subject.

Comment: @Martin: Finally, the book of Ghys and de la Harpe seems to be nice too. Since you answered my question, I think you may post these references as an answer.

Comment: I will do that, but only in about two weeks. I will meet a friend of mine who is working on the subject and I will ask him whether he knows better references and report back.

Comment: @Martin: Any news?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just mention the references given by Martin:

- [Sur les groupes hyperboliques d'après Mikhael Gromov](http://books.google.fr/books?id=FIGBAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), by Etienne Ghys and Pierre de la Harpe.
- [Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3DjaqB08AwAC&redir_esc=y), by Martin Bridson and André Häfliger.
- [Géométrie et théorie des groupes: les groupes hyperboliques de Gromov](http://books.google.fr/books?id=F78ZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), by Michel Coornaert, Thomas Delzant and Athanase Papadopoulos.

For my question, I found the third reference better.

Comment: My apologies for not following up on this earlier (I didn't see your comment). My colleague didn't have further suggestions, but she pointed out that Buyalo had some related results in [Geodesics in Hadamard spaces](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/aa988), Algebra i Analiz, 10:2 (1998), 93–123 (there is an English translation).

Comment: I will simply mention the "American" version of the "French" and "Swiss" versions of the notes mentioned above: http://www.cmi.univ-mrs.fr/~hamish/Papers/MSRInotes2004.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

A very accessible and well-written reference that covers this is Bonahon's book [Low dimensional topology: from Euclidean surfaces to hyperbolic knots](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~fbonahon/STML49.html).  There is also the added advantage of the author's magnificent moustache which can be seen on the back cover.